# How to setup dual domain to point to a home server with dynamic IP?

Tags: networking, dns, ddns

Here is a short description of my situation:
I am running a Ubuntu home server which also acts as DHCP/DNS for my private network. It is exposed to the outside network using DMZ, so one may access it from the outside. Up to this time I was using No-IP domain (let's name it `noip.domain.net` for the sake of better understanding) since my network has dynamic global IP address and I had to use DDNS functionality. I have recently purchased a domain name (let's name it `example.pl`) and I want it to point it to the same home server.
Is it possible to setup both domains to guide traffic to my home server? I am quite new to the topic so I would really appreciate more elaborate explanations and maybe some guidance steps. The home server is using Bind9 and also I have full access to my `example.pl` DNS records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem:
**Step 1.** I pointed DNS server of my `example.pl` to `noipdomain.net` which is my home server running Bind9 DNS.
**Step 2.** I created a new zone for `example.pl` with random `A` records.
**Step 3.** I created a simple python script that runs every 5 minutes and updates `A` records basing on the output of `dig +short noipdomain.net` command.
Note: Changing TTL to 5min is not a bad idea in this scenario
**Step 4.** Both domain currently point to the same IP and are accessible.

Comment: how did you "point" the DNS server to a different domain?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use DDNS for your domain. You can setup the domain name at whatever provider you used to register the domain name. How exactly depends on the interface you of your provider, here is an example for [Namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/595/11/how-do-i-enable-dynamic-dns-for-a-domain)

Comment: Sadly I do not have the DDNS option in my domain provider's offer. The only option is to edit DNS records. Is there another way of reaching my `homeserver` e.g. through `noip.domain.net`? I mean to setup a chain like this: I already have `noip.domain.net` -> `homeserver` and since `homeserver` is accessible under `noip.domain.net` and runs DNS maybe there is a way to resolve `example.pl` -> `homeserver` by using `noip.domain.net` as a NS record or at least `example.pl` -> `noip.domain.net` -> `homeserver`.

Comment: @kwojcikowski you could do a redirect from your `example.pl` domain to your `noip.domain.net` instead of using the A-Record. But if you don't have that option your out of luck and I would suggest to get a different provider. I don't understand your chain but keep in mind updates through the servers of the DNS takes time, I don't thing it's a good idea to use the A-Record for frequently changing IPs.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done - with limitations.  Forget any notion of running your own nameserver (is bind). To do this competently requires a minimum if 2 static IP addresses, arguably on 2 network connections. Name service is cheap - likely included with your domain registration - just use that.

The bit you are needing (as per your question) is to set up a CNAME record for example.pl to noip.domain.net.   This will mean that example.pl will resolve to the A record for noip.domain.net - and will work fine for services that only require to resolve a domain to an IP address. It will not work for email.

If instead you can use [www.example.pl](http://www.example.pl) - do that instead. In this way you are free to (in your domain providers DNS) set up things like mail records. (I note most ISPs will let you set up an MX and cname for the same record - this won't work in practice as cnames do not work the way one might intuitively expect)

(At least for web services) you can point multiple names to the same IP address (directly or indirectly eg via cnsme) and configure the web server to do name based virtual hosting (which is ubiquitous) so you can have multiple websites associated with 1 IP address.